# awk substr several times in a row

Tags: awk

I am using `awk substr()` to extract a sub string from the string.

For example if my string looks like this:

```
qwertyuiop
```

And I want to extract (1-3) & (6-9) characters I use this:

```
awk '{print (substr($1, 1, 3) substr($1, 6, 4))}'  
qweyui
```

How can I repeat a specific subtraction several times?

For example, I want to extract (1-3) & (6-9)(6-9)(6-9) characters to get the result like ths:

```
qweyuioyuioyuio
```

Of course I can use a command like this:

```
awk '{print (substr($1, 1, 3) substr($1, 6, 4) substr($1, 6, 4) substr($1, 6, 4))}'
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: assign the value of the substr to a variable, then repeat printing the variable? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the solutions to such a problem (messy but works).

```
 echo qwertyuiop | awk '{m=substr($1, 6, 4); {while (count++<3) string=string m; 
 print substr($1, 1, 3) string}}' 

 qweyuioyuioyuio
```

Answer (score 3):

Provided you want to extract non overlapping substrings, you can use the fixed column width option of gawk:

```
echo "qwertyuiop" | gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS="3 2 4" '{ print $1 $3 $3 $3 }'
```

You define 3 columns. The first one is 3 characters wide (this is the same as substr($1, 1, 3)). The second one is 2 characters wide (and we will ignore it). The 3rd is your second substring (substr($1, 6, 4)).

The you can directly print the fields you have defined.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Constant-Size

Comment: Personally, I think your first clause is a deal breaker. `FIELDWIDTHS` should really only be used for fixed-width data processing.

Comment: Which is particularly appropriate if the data is made of fixed-width fields... If the data to read is non overlapping, this is better that using several substr().

Answer (score 1):

There is a [delightful post](http://ben-zine.livejournal.com/9258.html) explaining various ways of repeating string in awk.

I'll quote the most obvious:

```
function rep1(s,n,      r) {
# O(n) allocate/appends
# 2 lines of code
# This is the simplest possible solution that will work:
# just repeatedly append the input string onto the value
# that will be passed back, decrementing the input count
# until it reaches zero.
        while (n-->0) r = r s;
        return r;
}
```

PS: The large amount of space before function parameter in `awk` indicates that this parameter is used as temporary local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can simply save the substring to a variable, then re-print it as needed. Don't forget to set a null `OFS`:

```
awk '{ print substr($1, 1, 3), x = (substr($1, 6, 4)), x, x }' OFS=
```

Testing:

```
echo "qwertyuiop" | awk '{ print substr($1, 1, 3), x = (substr($1, 6, 4)), x, x }' OFS=
```

Results:

```
qweyuioyuioyuio
```

---

If you need to print something more than three or four times, it may be worthwhile using a `for` loop:

```
echo "qwertyuiop" | awk '{ for(i=1;i<=5;i++) x = x substr($1, 6, 4); print substr($1, 1, 3), x }' OFS=
```

Results:

```
qweyuioyuioyuioyuioyuio
```